# No Output Directory named "build" found after the Build completed

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, mern, vercel

`Error: No Output Directory named "build" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings. Learn More: https://vercel.link/missing-public-directory STATIC_BUILD_NO_OUT_DIR: No Output Directory named "build" found after the Build completed. You can configure the Output Directory in your Project Settings.`

I am trying to deploy my app on Vercel but I am getting this error. What's the fix?
here is my code: https://github.com/Hamza-Azeem1/MERN-chatapp.git

I am overriding the output directory in the Vercel project setting but I am getting the same error.